# DateTime working onUWP PC but not on UWP Raspberry Pi

Tags: c#, uwp, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-universal, windows-10-iot-core

Ive build an UI for a Touchdisplay on Rpi with Windows 10 iot Core.

When I tested this on my PC it worked. If I now test the software on the Raspberry I get an exception on this line(s):

```
lblTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
lblDay.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd");
```

Its an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' what means this DateTime.Now is null Right?

The time is set on the Windows Device Portal so idk why there ist no "Now"-Time

Comment: I would be surprise that would be the case, `DateTime` is a non-nullable struct, so something would have to be `null` **within** the `DateTime` implementation and that is quite unlikely. I guess `lblTime` or `lblDay` is `null`. Set a breakpoint and see the values of the variables

Comment: Post the full exception text that's returned if you call `Exception.ToString()`. I'm pretty sure you'll find that `lblTime` or `lblDay` are null. DateTime is a struct and thus *non*nullable. It's data is [a single `UInt64` tick count](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,138) and thus non-nullable as well

Answer (score 1):

I would guess, that `lblTime` and/or `lblDay` is null.

You can simply debug this by using a null check (`if(lblTime == null) {`)

Comment: "Yeah, it could possibly mean that Now is null" - no, it couldn't mean that as `DateTime` is a non-nullable value type. I agree with your expectation that it's more likely that `lblTime` or `lblDay` is null, but it's worth removing the first sentence from your answer - and fixing your null check to be in C#, as that's the language the OP is using.

Answer (score 0):

I have now found the Problem. It was just to early(some first lines in the Main Page method), some Code later it worked fine.